# Combined update and replacement in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, replace

So I have two lists.  One has all the categories in it, the other only has categories that need to be reviewed.

`List_one = ('Maths', 'English', 'Science')`

`List_two = ('Maths:2', 'Science:4')`

I would like to have one complete list, that would look like the following:

`List_three = ('Maths:2', 'English', 'Science:4')`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure those lists shouldn't be a dict like `{'Maths': 2, 'Science': 4}`? That would likely be a lot easier to work with.

Comment: those are not lists, those are `tuples`

Comment: I am reading terminal output for grep -r -c -i string *.txt .  Each line of output becomes a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve performance by creating an intermediate `dict` to perform constant time lookup when carrying out replacement.

```
dict_two = {x.split(':')[0] : x for x in List_two}

out = [dict_two.get(x, x) for x in List_one]
print(out) 
['Maths:2', 'English', 'Science:4']
```

Using `dict.get`, you can replace list elements and avoid `KeyError`s at the same time, in `O(n)` time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Coldspeed pointed out the most performant approach. The naive approach would be

```
List_one = ('Maths', 'English', 'Science')

List_two = ('Maths:2', 'Science:4')

list_three  = tuple(x for x in List_one if not any(y.split(":")[0]==x for y in List_two)) + List_two
```

that removes items of list one that have a match in list two then add list two. But performance is bad because of the implicit `any` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
List_one = ('Maths', 'English', 'Science')
List_two = ('Maths:2', 'Science:4')
import copy
List_temp = list(copy.copy(List_one)) #Creating a copy of your original list
```

Output of List_temp:

['Maths', 'English', 'Science']

```
#Iterate through each element of List_temp and compare the strings with each element of List_two

#Have used python's inbuilt substring operator to compare the lists

for i in List_temp:
List_three = []
for j in range(len(List_two)):
    if str(i) in str(List_two[j]):
        y = i
        List_temp.remove(y) #Remove the elements present in List_two
List_three = List_two + tuple(List_temp) #Since we cant merge a tuple and list, have converted List_temp to tuple and added them to create a new tuple called List_three
print(List_three)
```

Output of code:

('Maths:2', 'Science:4', 'English')

Hope this helps